# IPsec Tunnel mode - RoadWarriors configuration

Tags: vpn, tunneling, ipsec

I've the need to configure IPsec tunnel mode between a gateway with static NAT (let's say its public IP is `172.31.0.105`) and a number of clients that are behind dynamic NAT.

Reading through some resources (as [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/racoon_roadwarrior_vpn), [this](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/network/ipsec/rasvpn.html), and [this](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x304.html)) I've found that the roadwarrior configuration should work for my case.

I've properly managed to setup and start racoon in both my gateway and in a test client, and when I try to setup the vpn from the client (`racoonctl vc -u user 172.31.0.105`) I obtain the banner specified in the server.

But somehow something it's wrong, and they cannot communicate.

Here is the `racoon.conf` on the gateway:

```
path certificate "/etc/racoon/certs";

listen {
        adminsock disabled;
        isakmp 172.31.0.105[500];
        isakmp_natt 172.31.0.105[4500];
}

timer
{
        natt_keepalive 600 sec;
}

# Phase 1 configuration
remote anonymous {
    exchange_mode aggressive;

    my_identifier asn1dn;
    certificate_type x509 "cert.pem" "key.pem";

    proposal_check claim;
    generate_policy on;
    verify_cert off;

    nat_traversal on;
    dpd_delay 20;   
    ike_frag on;     

    proposal {
        authentication_method hybrid_rsa_server;
        encryption_algorithm 3des;
        hash_algorithm md5;
        dh_group 2;
    }
}

# Local network information
mode_cfg {
    network4 172.31.0.200;    
    netmask4 255.255.255.0;   
    dns4 8.8.8.8;             
    #wins4 10.0.12.1;          
    pool_size 10;              
    auth_source system;        
    banner "/etc/racoon/motd"; 
    pfs_group 2;
}          

# Phase 2 proposal
sainfo anonymous {
    pfs_group 2;
    lifetime time 1 hour;
    encryption_algorithm 3des;
    authentication_algorithm hmac_md5;
    compression_algorithm deflate;
}
```

Here is the `racoon.conf` on the test client:

```
path certificate "/etc/racoon";
path pre_shared_key "/etc/racoon/psk.txt";

listen {
    adminsock "/var/racoon/racoon.sock" "root" "operator" 0660;
}

# Here is the address of the VPN gateway
remote 172.31.0.105 {
  exchange_mode aggressive;
  ca_type x509 "cacert.pem";
  proposal_check obey;
  nat_traversal on;
  ike_frag on;
  mode_cfg on;
  passive off;
  verify_cert off;
  script "/etc/racoon/phase1-up.sh" phase1_up;
  script "/etc/racoon/phase1-down.sh" phase1_down;
  proposal {
    encryption_algorithm 3des;
    hash_algorithm md5;
    authentication_method hybrid_rsa_client;
    dh_group 2;
  }
}


sainfo anonymous {
        pfs_group 2;
        lifetime time 1 hour;
        encryption_algorithm 3des;
        authentication_algorithm hmac_md5;
        compression_algorithm deflate ;
}
```

Here are the dump of the SPD entries, while the set of SAD entries is empty:

```
root@test-client:/etc/racoon# setkey -PD
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:49 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=267 seq=1 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:49 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=276 seq=2 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:49 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=283 seq=3 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:49 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=292 seq=4 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:50 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=299 seq=5 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:50 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=308 seq=6 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:50 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=315 seq=7 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: Jan  1 02:28:50 1970  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=324 seq=8 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
172.31.0.200[any] 0.0.0.0/0[any] any
    out prio def ipsec
    esp/tunnel/192.168.66.105-172.31.0.105/require
    created: May 23 13:30:05 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=345 seq=9 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
0.0.0.0/0[any] 172.31.0.200[any] any
    in prio def ipsec
    esp/tunnel/172.31.0.105-192.168.66.105/require
    created: May 23 13:30:05 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=352 seq=10 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: May 23 13:38:00 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=371 seq=11 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: May 23 13:38:00 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=380 seq=12 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: May 23 13:38:01 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=387 seq=13 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
(per-socket policy) 
    Policy:[Invalid direciton]
    created: May 23 13:38:01 2014  lastused:                     
    lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
    spid=396 seq=0 pid=2489
    refcnt=1
```

The client succesfully setup a new network interface:

```
eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.31.0.200  Bcast:172.31.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

but when from the gateway I try to ping the client (or also to establish a netcat session) using this virtual IP (`172.31.0.200`) I get an

```
Destination Host Unreachable
```